# How to reference a produced artifact of the sub-project from the test source in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Java project with the following structure:

```
 <root>
 |
 +-- src/main/java/...<my_code>
 |    
 +-- src/test/java/...<my_test_code>
 |    
 +-- <mock-artifact1>
 |  |  
 |  +-- src/main/java...
 |
 +-- <mock-artifact2>
 |  |  
 |  +-- src/main/java...
```

I'd like to build the jar-s from the mock-artifact1 and mock-artifact2 and then use these jars in the runtime of the tests. How should I set the dependencies of the Gradle project so that these artifacts would be already built before the tests start?
And by the way, how to ask gradle not to deploy these artifacts with the root project (because they are necessary for the tests only)

P.s. for more understanding I would say that I'm writing a bytecode analyzer which takes jar-files as an input, and a problem is how to write tests for it using Gradle.

Comment: learn more about setting up gradle multi-projects: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make your project multi module structure like.

in your root module add file:
  settings.gradle

```
include 'mock-artifact1', 'mock-artifact2'
```

Then in your root project in gradle build file you can add dependecies in scope of your configuration. If you have typical java base project with 'plugin java'
you can add in dependencies lines:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':mock-artifact1')
    compile project(':mock-artifact2')
}
```

or if you want to have just in test runtime add:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile project(':mock-artifact1')
    testCompile project(':mock-artifact2')
}
```

Gradle configuration is a bit tricky, if you'll have some problem post me